# Why calling wait() more than once is not throwing Exceptions?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I know calling the `wait()` method without getting ownership on object would lead to Exception.
and From Java doc,on calling the `wait()`
The thread
     * releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread
     * notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up
     * either through a call to he `{@code notify}` method or the
     * `{@code notifyAll}` method.
so once `wait()` is called on object,that particular thread looses ownership on that on that object,until some other thread notifies it.

Why does calling `wait()` twice without notifying,not throwing an error?
To make sure,..I just ran producer,so no other thread's i there to notify it and `wait()` method is called infinite times.
Yet despite loosing ownership of that after first `wait()` call,the subsequent wait calls should throw exceptions.isn't?but why is it working fine?

```
class Producer extends Thread {

    private Queue<Integer> queue;
    private int maxSize;

    public Producer(Queue<Integer> queue, int maxSize, String name) {
        super(name);
        this.queue = queue;
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (queue) {
                try {
                    queue.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "more than once"?  Do you call the `run()` method above from different threads?  (Maybe it's called from some code you haven't shown us?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only run that thread, it will block after (in) the wait (try adding a debug output).

`wait()` blocks until notified, and reacquires the lock before returning. I.e., when `wait()` returns in your example, you again have locked `queue`.

**Edit: per update of question**

Thus, "calling `wait()` twice without notifying" is not possible, as the first call to `wait()` will block the thread until notified. It cannot be called infinite times in the loop, it either blocks or throws an exception.

**Addition:**

By the way, having a "naked" wait is often risky, as there is no guarantee which of the waiting threads is woken up (e.g., a producer or a consumer).
A common idiom (as Java "built-in monitors" -- `synchronized` blocks -- do not have condition variables) is something like

```
while(! condition)
    wait();
```

In this case, for a consumer, perhaps something like

```
while(queue.isEmpty())
    wait();
```

Comment: If this answers your question, yes, you're not looping here, you're calling `wait()` once and then your code stops, until notified or an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Sriharsha, if it answers your question, please accept the answer.  If not,  please clarify and I'll try to update the answer.

Comment: @SRobertz,Please update your answer as it  wasn't pointing my question,"why calling wait() more than once without notify is not throwing exception",so it was kind of unclear. None the less,i got the point from the comments  that it wasn't looping rather,its just waiting to get notified . So doubt is clarified

Comment: You write that "`wait()` method is called infinite times. That should not happen. Have you verified that it does with e.g. a debug printout? If so, you need to show more code, because that should not happen.

Comment: @SRobertz,Yes.Thanks :)